# Efficient algorithm for hashing subgraphs?

Tags: algorithm, hash, graph-algorithm

Is there an algorithm for hashing subgraphs (consisting of the nodes and edges) of a given graph? Similarly, the particular graph I am talking about is a molecular network, and the intent of hashing the subgraph of the network is to see if given a different network, there is a particular subgraph that matches the previously hashed subgraph.

I am not concerned with the runtime of finding all the subgraphs themselves. I am concerned with given a particular hashed subgraph, and another subgraph, whether I can discover if the subgraph is one that I have seen before in O(1) time.

Comment: How do you define a subgraph? Are the nodes the same (identity), or do they have the same value?

Comment: Edited. A subgraph consists of the nodes as well as any edges (directed or undirected).

Comment: How would hashing subgraphs work?  I am skeptical that this could possibly work.  If your hashing scheme worked, you could solve graph isomorphism simply.  IIRC, graph isomorphism is hard.

Comment: I am not suggesting that differently labeled subgraphs are the same subgraph. I'm saying that given the specifically named nodes and edges, are the two subgraphs the same. Might still not be possible though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your graph is acyclic (tree with variable splitting level), 
you can keep in the each vertex (node) of your graph some value, 
which is "hash of this subtree".

Computing hash for subtree is easy bt recursive algorithm, like:

```
// Initial value ~0 meaning "need to compute"
uint32_t subtree_hash(node *p) {
  for(int attempts = 0; p->hash == ~0; attempts++) {
    p->hash = compute_hash(p->value) + attempts;
    foreach node *child in (p->children) {
      p->hash = ((p->hash >> 7) | (p->hash << (32 - 7))) + subtree_hash(child);
  }
  return p->hash; // never ~0
}
```

Comment: I think you'd want to XOR the subtree_hash's of all the children so that order does not matter.

Comment: In the original request, order matter or is not matter - isn't specified. So, I assumed by default - order is matter, because of in the simplest case (binary tree), you cannot always change lson <-> rson without affecting tree structure. Of course, if order is not matter - need to disable rotation, and just adding values. XOR is not so good, because of, for example, if two children has equal hash values, their values will just cross our from result. If you use adding, there will be added 2x value. Crossed out only lowest bit of particular sum, but not whole sum.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that vertices have integer IDs, I would just hash the list of edges in the subgraph, in some defined order (e.g. lexicographic), using whatever hashing algorithm you would normally use to hash an array of pairs of integers.  Edges in this list are represented as pairs of vertices that have an inherent order, so if the graph you want to represent actually has undirected edges, you need to also order the pair of vertices within each edge in some order (e.g. from minimum to maximum).

Answer (score 0):

There is no efficient algorithm for hashing subgraphs, otherwise graph matching would be known to be polynomial.

Since molecular graphs have bounded connectivity, some specific algorithms exist.

Googling 'canonical molecular signature' I have found this online [tool](http://www.issb.genopole.fr/~faulon/sscan.php)